# How to display event hour by hour in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Create table tblEvent  ( Event_ID int, Start_Time datetime, End_Time datetime )

insert into tblEvent values(1,'2015-02-10 9:00:00.000','2015-02-10 11:00:00.000')
insert into tblEvent values(2,'2015-02-10 11:00:00.000','2015-02-10 11:20:00.000')
insert into tblEvent values(3,'2015-02-10 11:20:00.000','2015-02-10 13:00:00.000')
```

and want to be display like below

```
Hour  Event_ID  [Start_End]
9     1         9:00-10:00
10    1         10:00-11:00
11    2         11:00-11:20
11    3         11:20-12:00
12    3         12:00-13:00
```

and we can make the End_Time of Event 3 become 13:30
we had to be display

```
13    3         13:00-13:30
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEPART function

```
DATEPART(HOUR, [Start_End]) AS Hour
```

Comment: More of comment, dont you think ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select blocks.Hour, e.Event_Id,
    format(case when e.Start_Time > blocks.Start_Time then e.Start_Time else blocks.Start_Time end, 'HH:mm') +
    '-' +
    format(case when e.End_Time < blocks.End_Time then e.End_Time else blocks.End_Time end, 'HH:mm')
from
    tblEvent as e inner join
    (
    select
        d0.n + d1.n * 4 as Hour,
        dateadd(hh, d0.n + d1.n * 4,     cast(cast(current_timestamp as date) as datetime)) as Start_Time,
        dateadd(hh, d0.n + d1.n * 4 + 1, cast(cast(current_timestamp as date) as datetime)) as End_Time
    from 
        (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) as d0,
        (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5) as d1
    ) as blocks
        on blocks.End_Time > e.Start_Time and blocks.Start_Time < e.End_Time
order by Event_Id, Hour
```

Here's a start. SQL Server? Is current day enough? You don't have the `format()` on SQL 2008 so you'll have to do that part yourself.

I'm not sure this handles all the cases exactly the way you want. You can take the basic idea and extend it across a longer range of hours, say 168 for a full week.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/819c0/9

Answer (score 0):

TRY Some thing like this.This sample data is running ok.

Please provide another sample data atleast 10 rows and don't forget to paste desired output.

Also read my comment in script.

```
DECLARE @tblEvent TABLE (
    Event_ID INT
    ,Start_Time DATETIME
    ,End_Time DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO @tblEvent
VALUES (
    1
    ,'2015-02-10 9:00:00.000'
    ,'2015-02-10 11:00:00.000'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'2015-02-10 11:00:00.000'
    ,'2015-02-10 11:20:00.000'
    )
    ,(
    3
    ,'2015-02-10 11:20:00.000'
    ,'2015-02-10 13:00:00.000'
    );
    --select *,DATEdiff(hour,a.Start_Time,a.End_Time) from @tblEvent a
    ;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY Start_Time
            ) RN
        ,DATEdiff(hour, Start_Time, End_Time) Diff
    FROM @tblEvent
    )
    --select * from cte
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT Event_ID
        ,Start_Time
        ,CASE 
            WHEN Diff > 1
                THEN DATEADD(minute, 60 - DATEPART(minute, Start_Time), Start_Time)
            ELSE End_Time
            END End_Time
        ,RN
        ,DIFF
        ,1 RN1
        ,DATEPART(minute, Start_Time) DIFFMIN
    FROM CTE
    --WHERE RN = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN A.Diff > B.DIFF
                THEN b.Event_ID
            ELSE a.Event_ID
            END
        ,B.End_Time Start_Time
        ,CASE 
            WHEN A.Diff > B.DIFF
                THEN DATEADD(minute, 60 - DATEPART(minute, B.Start_Time), B.End_Time)
            ELSE A.End_Time
            END End_Time
        ,CASE 
            WHEN A.Diff > B.DIFF
                THEN B.RN
            ELSE B.RN + 1
            END RN
        ,CASE 
            WHEN A.Diff > B.DIFF
                THEN B.DIFF - 1
            ELSE A.Diff
            END
        ,RN1 + 1
        ,0
    FROM CTE1 B
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT *
        FROM CTE
        WHERE RN = B.RN
        ) A
    WHERE B.DIFF > 0
    )
SELECT [Hour]
    ,Event_ID
    ,[Start_End]
FROM (
    SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, Start_Time) [Hour]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Start_Time ORDER BY Start_Time
            ) RN2
        ,Event_ID
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Start_Time, 114) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), End_Time, 114) [Start_End]
    FROM CTE1
    ) TBL
WHERE RN2 = 1

    --BELOW QUERY RETURN 6 ROWS
    -- I AM TRYING TO ELIMINATE THE EXTRA ROWS WITHOUT ROW_NUMBER
   --WHICH WOULD BE MORE OPTIMIZE,BUT I AM NOT GETTING WHAT ACTUALLY CAUSING THIS BEHAVIOUR
    --MEANWHILE YOU CAN TEST OTHER SAMPLE DATA,AND THROW OTHER SAMPLE DATA

    --SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, Start_Time) [Hour]
    --      ,Event_ID
    --      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Start_Time, 114) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), End_Time, 114) [Start_End]
    --  FROM CTE1
```